ROS 2 humble hawksbill's rviz 2 not able to load either STL or DAE files. How can i resolve this?
I'm sharing details for this issue only with the STL file but the same issue is occurring with the DAE file as well. I've checked to make sure that the STL file is located exactly where rviz 2 is unable to load it from. It seems to be a commonplace issue based on my search results but none of the posts that i found had any clear solutions.
rviz 2 messages:
URDF
Errors loading geometries:
• for link 'camera_link':
Could not load mesh resource '/root/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh/d415.stl'
Could not load mesh resource '/root/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh/d415.stl'

terminal messages:
root@LAPTOP:~/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/launch# ls
__pycache__  cylinder.launch.py  d415.launch.py  d435.launch.py
root@LAPTOP:~/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/launch# ros2 launch d415.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /root/.ros/log/2024-07-16-14-08-09-182459-LAPTOP-574
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [576]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process started with pid [578]
[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process started with pid [580]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-4]: process started with pid [582]
[static_transform_publisher-4] [INFO] [1721128089.460436962] [static_transform_publisher_vpRMeKQ26HcsRFjM]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-4] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-4] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-4] from 'world' to 'base_link'
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507013113] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507284573] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_bottom_screw_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507304501] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_color_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507317576] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_color_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507330039] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_depth_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507336883] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_depth_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507342834] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_left_ir_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507349968] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_left_ir_optical_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507375246] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507383191] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_right_ir_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128089.507389754] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment camera_right_ir_optical_frame
[rviz2-3] QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
[joint_state_publisher-2] [INFO] [1721128089.863639976] [joint_state_publisher]: Waiting for robot_description to be published on the robot_description topic...
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1721128090.134187692] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1721128090.134355643] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.5 (GLSL 4.5)
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1721128090.217464479] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [ERROR] [1721128191.533445789] [rviz2]: Error retrieving file [/root/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh/d415.stl]: 
[rviz2-3] [ERROR] [1721128191.533604262] [rviz2]: Error retrieving file [/root/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh/d415.stl]: 
^C[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1721128294.986179628] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[static_transform_publisher-4] [INFO] [1721128294.986173473] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1721128294.986174046] [rclcpp]: signal_handler(signum=2)
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process has finished cleanly [pid 576]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 582]
[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process has finished cleanly [pid 580]
[INFO] [joint_state_publisher-2]: process has finished cleanly [pid 578]
root@LAPTOP:~/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/launch# cd /root/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh/
root@LAPTOP:~/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh# ls
d415.stl  d435.dae
root@LAPTOP:~/ws/assets/demo-01/test_01/mesh# 

python launch file:
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue

def generate_launch_description():

    use_xacro = LaunchConfiguration('use_xacro')
    urdf_file = LaunchConfiguration('urdf_file')
    xacro_file = LaunchConfiguration('xacro_file')

    pkg_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    mesh_path = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'mesh')

    default_urdf_file = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'urdf', '_d415.urdf')
    default_xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path, 'urdf', 'test_d415_camera.urdf.xacro') # _d415.urdf.xacro

    declare_xacro_file = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'xacro_file',
        default_value=default_xacro_file,
        description='Path to Xacro file'
    )

    robot_description = ParameterValue(Command(['xacro ', LaunchConfiguration('xacro_file'), ' mesh_path:=', mesh_path]),
                                       value_type=str)

    robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}],
    )

    joint_state_publisher = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
    )

    rviz2 = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', os.path.join(pkg_path, 'rviz', 'urdf_config.rviz')],
    )

    tf2 = Node(
            package='tf2_ros',
            executable='static_transform_publisher',
            arguments = ['--x', '0', '--y', '0', '--z', '0', '--yaw', '0', '--pitch', '0', '--roll', '0', '--frame-id', 'world', '--child-frame-id', 'base_link']
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        declare_xacro_file,
        robot_state_publisher,
        joint_state_publisher,
        rviz2,
        tf2
    ])

.

I managed to find the solution in an over ten years old post! Apparently, the mesh files need to be contained in a package that has been built & sourced properly, with their file & directory addresses named accordingly. I was able to load the mesh files after ensuring that their addresses were correct with reference to the package name, followed by using the "colcon build" & "source install/setup[dot]sh" commands in the terminal, before running the python launch file.


I've checked to make sure that the STL file is located exactly where rviz 2 is unable to load it from

Have you verified that the mesh directory is being installed? i.e., when you write the CMakeLists file, have you installed the mesh directory with the rest of your directories?
A good way to verify this would be to a). Check your CMakeLists for the description package, and b). Check your install space to verify that the stls are exported over to the install space (you can look into the install directory followed by your package name to find out)

I checked it just now. The mesh directory is present together with the urdf directory in the install space. The STL & DAE files were included there too.

From your stack trace, I see that you're launching directly from the launch directory. Can you try to launch instead from the root of the workspace? I guess in this case it would be ros2 launch test_01 d415.launch.py It might be that since you are inside the launch directory it cannot find the STLs

I checked the directory address that rviz 2 was checking for files by copying it from the error message. The files are in there but it couldn't detect them. The package isn't installed, since i was just trying things out, so i can't run it from the root.
